# Looking for a combinatorial proof of an identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities

I've come up with an interesting combinatorial identity (thanks to P. Belmans who precomputed the numbers and pointed out to me that they correspond to [OEIS A002697](https://oeis.org/A002697)):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+1-i}{2}\binom{2n+1}{i} = n\cdot 4^{n-1}.
$$

To me, the RHS has an obvious combinatorial interpretation. Namely, it is the number of ways to choose two intersecting subsets $X,Y\subset \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ and an element $x\in X\cap Y$.

I can prove the identity by hand, using induction. My question is whether there is a nice combinatorial proof of the identity above.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the LHS can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(n-i)^2\binom{2n}{i}.
$$

Comment: I am guessing that $A=X$ and $B=Y$ and $g=n$; but please write the question more carefully.

Comment: @NeilStrickland My bad! Fixed

Comment: It might be noted that the identity can be generalized to $$\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{m+a-i}{a}\binom{2m+a+1}{i} = 4^m\binom{m+a/2}{m}.$$ The original identity is the case $m=n-1, a=2$.

Comment: By symmetry, your LHS rewrite is also $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-i)^2 \binom{2n}{i}$.

Comment: Continuing from this, the L.H.S is $\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{i=0}^{2n} (2n-i)^2\binom{2n}{i}-n^24^n)=4^n\sigma^2_{2n}=n4^{n-1}$, (binomail varience) as $(n-i)$ is odd around $n$.

Comment: @AlapanDas oh, that’s a very cool explanation!

Comment: Another generalization: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247818/how-can-i-prove-this-combinatorial-identity-sum-j-0n-j-binom2nnj-binom